# Connecting SAP API Management to SuccessFactors using OAuth Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, sap-business-technology-platform, sap, sap-successfactors

I am working on creating an API proxy in SAP API Management (SAP APIM) which connects to SuccessFactors system using OAuth credentials. I followed [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/03/09/sap-cloud-platform-api-management-secure-connectivity-oauth-to-sap-successfactors-employee-central-apis/comment-page-1/#comment-669926) link for the required policies, but later found that the Idp endpoint (/oath/idp) for getting the saml assertion is being deprecated and should not be used anymore.

Now I am looking for alternatives to get the saml bearer assertion to use it further in Oauth process.

I found blogs explaining about using using an offline tool or Microsoft Azure for assertion generation. I am looking for guidance to know if these are the only options. and how to incorporate them in APIM proxy policy. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find answers? The offline tool is basically a java application, which creates a signed SAML Assertion. So everything which creates a signed SAML Assertion should be fine (e.g. Azure, Okta, Auth0 and so on).